# how to convert string into date format

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting value `date="20120120"` and I want to convert it date format like 
it should print `2012-01-20 [YYYY-MM-dd]`.

Comment: simpleDateFormat - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
 String mytime="20120120";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd");
        Date myDate = null;
        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

        System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrr"+finalDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
public static String convertStringToDate(String startDate) throws ParseException
{
    String myFormatString = "yyyyMdd"; // your current date format
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
    Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);

    DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");  // Date format you want
    return dateFormat.format(startingDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the methods which convert your data :

```
public String DateConverter(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat smf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dt = null;
    try {
        dt = smf.parse(start_of_event);
        // et = smf.parse(end_of_event);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    smf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMMM dd,yyyy");
    date = smf.format(dt);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
Date d = dateFormat.parse("string")
```

You can also follow the [link here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/String_to_Date_Formatting_Using_Java_%28Android%29).